# Is it possible to have two logos in Magento Store?

Tags: magento-1.9, logo

I want to have one logo (say maybe a white logo) for my Main Page and another one to be shown on the Show Search Results page (maybe the same logo but black).
Is it possible to achieve that in Magento 1.9.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep your current logo in all pages then display another one just in the `search result page`, you can follow this:

1) Go to `app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/page/html/header.phtml` or sometimes certain themes provide several themes and they are located in general in : `app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/page/html/header/header4.phtml` for exemple

2) replace this:

```
<div class="header-container"> //This class may change
    <div class="header">      //This class may change
        <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()): ?>
            <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
        <?php endif ?>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

With:

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
        <?php $currentLayoutHandle = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles(); ?>
        <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()): ?>
            <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php elseif (in_array('catalogsearch_result_index', $currentLayoutHandle)): ?>
            <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getskinUrl('images/logo2.png') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
        <?php endif ?>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

3) Go to `skin/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/images` then copy your 2nd logo Inside for exemple `logo2.png`

Comment: Is possible using the same theme for store two, and customized the only store 2 themes without affecting store 1.

Comment: Yes you have to create a copy of the first thème and in admin, you have to set this new theme in your second store view scope